# Can CNN do better than pretrained CNN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

With all I know. pretrained CNN can do way better than CNN. I have a dataset of 855 images. I have applied CNN and got 94% accuracy.Then I applied Pretrained model (VGG16, ResNet50, Inception_V3, MobileNet)also with fine tuning but still i got highest 60% and two of them are doing very bad on classification. Can CNN really do better than pretrained model or my implementation is wrong. I've converted my image into 100 by 100 dimensions and followed the way of [keras application](https://keras.io/applications/). Then What is  the issue ??

Naive CNN approach :

```
def cnn_model():
    size = (100,100,1)
    num_cnn_layers =2
    NUM_FILTERS = 32
    KERNEL = (3, 3)
    MAX_NEURONS = 120

    model = Sequential()

    for i in range(1, num_cnn_layers+1):
        if i == 1:
            model.add(Conv2D(NUM_FILTERS*i, KERNEL, input_shape=size, 
            activation='relu', padding='same'))
        else:
            model.add(Conv2D(NUM_FILTERS*i, KERNEL, activation='relu', 
            padding='same'))

    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(int(MAX_NEURONS), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Dense(int(MAX_NEURONS/2), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.4))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', 
    metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

VGG16 approach:

```
def vgg():
`  `vgg_model = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(weights='imagenet',include_top=False,input_shape = (100,100,3))
    model = Sequential()
    for layer in vgg_model.layers:
        model.add(layer)

    # Freeze the layers 
    for layer in model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False

    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-5),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're referring to as CNN in both cases talk about the same thing, which is a type of a neural network model. It's just that the pre-trained model has been trained on some other data instead of the dataset you're working on and trying to classify.

What is usually used here is called Transfer Learning. Instead of freezing all the layers, trying leaving the last few layers open so they can be retrained with your *own* data, so that the pretrained model can edit its weights and biases to match your needs as well. It could be the case that the dataset you're trying to classify is foreign to the pretrained models.

Here's an example from my own work, there are additional pieces of code but you can make it work with your own code, the logic remains the same

```
#You extract the layer which you want to manipulate, usually the last few.
last_layer = pre_trained_model.get_layer(name_of_layer)

# Flatten the output layer to 1 dimension
x = layers.Flatten()(last_output)
# Add a fully connected layer with 1,024 hidden units and ReLU activation
x = layers.Dense(1024,activation='relu')(x)
# Add a dropout rate of 0.2
x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)                  
# Add a final sigmoid layer for classification
x = layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(x)           

#Here we combine your newly added layers and the pre-trained model.
model = Model( pre_trained_model.input, x) 

model.compile(optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.0001), 
              loss = 'binary_crossentropy', 
              metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

Comment: For multi-class classification use 'softmax' funcion with 'categorical_crossentropy' loss function.

Comment: This was just an example from my own code. As you can see in my Dense layer, I only have 1 output, and used the functions appropriately. You can change the code however you like

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what @Ilknur Mustafa mentioned, as your dataset may be foreign to the images used for pre-training, you can try to re-train few last layers of the pre-trained model instead of adding a whole new layers. The below example code doesn't add any additional trainable layer other than the output layer. In this way, you can benefit by retraining the last few layers on the existing weights, rather than training from scratch. This may be beneficial if you don't have a large dataset to train on.

```
# load model without classifier layers 
vgg = VGG16(include_top=False, input_shape=(100, 100, 3), weights='imagenet', pooling='avg')
# make only last 2 conv layers trainable 
for layer in vgg.layers[:-4]:
    layer.trainable = False
# add output layer  
out_layer = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(vgg.layers[-1].output)
model_pre_vgg = Model(vgg.input, out_layer)
# compile model 
opt = SGD(lr=1e-5) 
model_pre_vgg.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#You extract the layer which you want to manipulate, usually the last few.
last_layer = pre_trained_model.get_layer(name_of_layer)

# Flatten the output layer to 1 dimension
x = layers.Flatten()(last_output)
# Add a fully connected layer with 1,024 hidden units and ReLU activation
x = layers.Dense(1024,activation='relu')(x)
# Add a dropout rate of 0.2
x = layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)                  
# Add a final sigmoid layer for classification
x = layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(x)           

#Here we combine your newly added layers and the pre-trained model.
model = Model( pre_trained_model.input, x) 

model.compile(optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.0001), 
              loss = 'binary_crossentropy', 
              metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32829936)